# Oracle XAException - XA Recovery Failed

Tags: oracle, hibernate, spring, jta, xa

I just started using bitronix for jta in my spring/hibernate setup and everything works fine under H2 and Postgres but fails under Oracle.

I followed other online posts about granting privileges, but the problem still persists.
Any ideas of how to fix this?

I set these Permisions:

```
GRANT SELECT ON sys.dba_pending_transactions TO user;
GRANT SELECT ON sys.pending_trans$ TO user;
GRANT SELECT ON sys.dba_2pc_pending TO user;
GRANT EXECUTE ON sys.dbms_system TO user:
```

And still got this error

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'liquibase' defined in class path resource [spring/liquibaseContext.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.JDBCException: Error updating database
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1455)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:519)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:294)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:225)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:585)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:913)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:464)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.createWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:282)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:204)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:47)
    at com.xxxx.spring.config.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:19)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:3934)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4429)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:791)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:771)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:526)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor(HostConfig.java:630)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptors(HostConfig.java:556)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:491)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.start(HostConfig.java:1206)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.lifecycleEvent(HostConfig.java:314)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:119)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1053)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.start(StandardHost.java:722)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1045)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.start(StandardEngine.java:443)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.start(StandardService.java:516)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.start(StandardServer.java:710)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:583)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:288)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:413)
Caused by: org.hibernate.JDBCException: Error updating database
    at com.xxx.db.liquibase.SpringLiquibase.afterPropertiesSet(SpringLiquibase.java:288)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1514)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1452)
    ... 37 more
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: unable to get a connection from pool of a PoolingDataSource containing an XAPool of resource xaDataSource with 5 connection(s) (5 still available) -failed-
    at bitronix.tm.resource.jdbc.PoolingDataSource.getConnection(PoolingDataSource.java:252)
    at com.xxxx.db.liquibase.SpringLiquibase.afterPropertiesSet(SpringLiquibase.java:280)
    ... 39 more
Caused by: bitronix.tm.internal.BitronixRuntimeException: incremental recovery failed when trying to acquire a connection from failed resource 'xaDataSource'
    at bitronix.tm.resource.common.XAPool.getConnectionHandle(XAPool.java:109)
    at bitronix.tm.resource.common.XAPool.getConnectionHandle(XAPool.java:97)
    at bitronix.tm.resource.jdbc.PoolingDataSource.getConnection(PoolingDataSource.java:248)
    ... 40 more
Caused by: bitronix.tm.recovery.RecoveryException: failed recovering resource xaDataSource
    at bitronix.tm.recovery.IncrementalRecoverer.recover(IncrementalRecoverer.java:104)
    at bitronix.tm.resource.common.XAPool.getConnectionHandle(XAPool.java:106)
    ... 42 more
Caused by: javax.transaction.xa.XAException
    at oracle.jdbc.xa.OracleXAResource.recover(OracleXAResource.java:709)
    at bitronix.tm.recovery.RecoveryHelper.recover(RecoveryHelper.java:103)
    at bitronix.tm.recovery.RecoveryHelper.recover(RecoveryHelper.java:61)
    at bitronix.tm.recovery.IncrementalRecoverer.recover(IncrementalRecoverer.java:64)
    ... 43 more
```

Comment: I got this problem using the following settings: Oracle11gR1 database, bitronix 2.1.2, Hibernate 3.3.2.GA, Hibernate dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect, XA Datasource class: oracle.jdbc.xa.client.OracleXADataSource, JDBC Driver class: oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver

(Also tried it with oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver)

Answer (score 1):

I can see two reasons for this problem:

1) Oracle changed the set of privileges recently

2) You haven't properly given the privileges to the user the connection pool is configured with.

If the problem is (1), you should provide the *exact* version of the DB and JDBC driver you're using then we can see what needs to be done to make this combination work

If it's (2), you should double-check your user's privileges. The easiest and safest way to do so is to connect to the DB using a JDBC client (like Squirrel SQL) and check that you can select from the 3 views you mentioned above as well as trying to check if you can execute one of the dbms_system stored procedures.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure how the issue was originally resolved.

However, I was also getting the same error and using the additional below query the issue was resolved.

```
grant execute on dbms_xa to <user>; --(If using Oracle 10.2.0.4 or higher JDBC driver)
```

[Reference](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?rs=0&q1=3979190&uid=swg21196663&loc=en_US&cs=utf-8&cc=us&lang=en)